# Understanding 'performance_metrics()' in Prophet, how it works and it's significance

Tags: time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I am working on time series forecasting using Prophet. In order to measure my model's performance, I have been calculating errors like MAE and MAPE by passing the cross validation dataframe into a self made function. For eg:

```
def MAPE(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = np.array(y_true)
    y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred)/y_true))*100
```

After running the model and generating cross validation df:

```
MAPE(cv.y, cv.yhat)
```

However, recently I came across the 'performance metrics' function in Prophet.
After passing my cv dataframe into this, I got this dataframe:

```
m = Prophet()
m.fit(temp)
future_temp = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq = 'M')
forecast_temp = m.predict(future_temp)
forecast_temp['key'] = 9253010010
cv = cross_validation(m,initial = '730 days', period = '31 days', horizon = '365 days')
#forecast_temp[['key', 'ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']]
#f = m.plot(forecast_temp)

ax = temp.plot(x='ds',y='y')
forecast_temp.plot(x='ds',y='yhat', ax=ax)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du5w5.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A8HF.png)

The error values I get in this dataframe are nowhere near the ones that I have calculated manually so far and I am not able to interpret this. Some of the questions I have are:
How is it calculating error values for different horizons?
Why does it start calculating errors from 32 days of horizon onwards?

I am new to this and any in depth explanation of this function and it's comparision to the manual approach of mine would be helpful.

Thanks!

I tried the manual approach to calculate errors but it gave results way different than the ones returned by 'performance metrics'. I am not able to interpret the dataframe being returned by it.